# The type or namespace name 'Service Host' could not be found in .NET5

Tags: wcf, .net-5

I recently converted my .NET framework WCF application to .NET5.

I am getting the `Service Host` could not be found error.

> 'File' does not contain a definition for 'GetAccessControl'

I have installed these nuget packages but no luck.
`System.ServiceModel.Primitives`
`System.ServiceModel.Http`
`System.ServiceModel.Security`
`System.ServiceModel.Duplex`
`System.ServiceModel.NetTcp`
`System.Private.ServiceModel`

I am not sure what is the replacement of `Service Host` and `Access Control` in .NET5.

Could someone please help me?

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Api));
  FileSecurity fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(outputFile);
```

Comment: You can check out this link : [ServiceHost Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicehost?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Jiayao the asker ask about .NET Core (NET 5.0) classes, not .NET Framework's ServiceHost. It is different, because ServiceHost is not part of default .NET Core SDK and runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The class libraries of System.ServiceModel.* (also commonly called WCF client) is available as separate nuget packages.

The most compatible version for .NET 5.0 is System.ServiceModel.* version 4.8.1 so you should use this version.

For ServiceHost, .NET Core does not provide this. Because this means that the code will act as WCF as server, not WCF client. Microsoft itself has stated that it won't support WCF as server based on this blog article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/supporting-the-community-with-wf-and-wcf-oss-projects/

Fortunately, there's an ongoing effort from OSS to provide WCF server support for .NET Core, and it's called CoreWCF:

https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

Currently (as far as I know) it supports BasicHttpBinding and TCP binding.